# Collision between SKSpriteNode and SKTileMapNode

Tags: ios, swift

In a mario-like platform game, when my Scene launches, I create a SKTileSet as well as a SKTileMapNode programmatically (using the editor is not an option).

For now, the map only contains the ground on which the player must walk.

I have successfully added the player as a SKSpriteNode, and added a physics body, so that the player falls from the sky, through the screen when the game launches.

The issue is, I can't figure out the best way to prevent the player from falling through the ground.

Should I add a physics body to each tile of the ground, or detect collisions and correct the position of the player? If I do so, why attach a physics body to the player at all, since I need to check and correct its position all the time?